# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 2

Tags: mysql, ssis

I configured mysql ODBC connector  in ODBC Data Source Configuration => test connection is OK.
When I try to use the mysql ODBC connector into SSIS project, it throws error "

> An error has occurred while connecting MySQL_5.1: ERROR [08S01]
>   [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting
>   for initial communication packet', system error: 2.

Thanks,
Tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are running the package on the same environment you are testing the connection, right?

If yes, I would check for package configurations. If you have them active, the values you set manually  on the data source may be replaced by the ones on the configuration.

If that isn't the problem, please post more info regarding when the error is occurring.

Comment: dsn=MySQL;server={name};uid=username;database=db_name;port=3306

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered with the same exception, but when our networking team removed the NAS(Network Attached Storage) drive from the database server, it solved the problem completely.

[Refer this site](http://codeandcalm.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/error-08s01-mysqlodbc-5-1-driverlost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-waiting-for-initial-communication-packet-system-error-2)