# Connection string with odbc connector

Tags: odbc

I am getting error

```
ERROR [08S01] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060.
```

While using connection string

"DRIVER={mysql odbc 5.1 Driver};SERVER=204.11.58.166;DATABASE=dbname;UID=uid;PASSWORD=uid;OPTION=3;"

So, please guide me how to solve it.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

What MySQL version are you using ? ( To see the version you can use 'SELECT VERSION();' )
Is MySQL 64b or 32b  ?
What is your OS ?

Try to update to ODBC 5.2, see on dev.mysql.com -> download -> conectors

Roberto Novakosky

---

Well I already have this in 3 situations

1) I was using old version of connection on Delphi, and with MySQL installed on Linux. I did update of my components and the connection was OK. (similar message)

2) In a remote application I used 'localhost' inside string connection, when must be the IP of server, on server works OK, but when I use from remote host this problem occurs. resolved with the real IP. (similar message)

3) In my LAN, the port 3306 was redirected to other machine, so when I tried to connect an outside server, the response connection was wrong. the message was exactly as yours. As, we can't to change the port of MySQL of outside server (that was 3306), I changed the port of my local MySQL server to 3307 and removed from my router the redirect over 3306. It was with conflict, see: I need to use 3306 from outside and it need to respond to my machine, the router hindered the connection ...

Good luck

Comment: I am using MYSQL5.0.72 and my OS is windows XP 32 BIT

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007488/ssis-package-mysql-odbc-connection-error/13817218#13817218) thread 
and [this](http://codeandcalm.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/error-08s01-mysqlodbc-5-1-driverlost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-waiting-for-initial-communication-packet-system-error-2) site for detailed explanation